# Passing Variable to Function That Calls Another Function That Needs to Use the Variable To Call A Different Variable

Tags: vba, excel

First time posting here so my apologies if I've made some mistakes or broken any unspoken rules. My Sub in VBA needs to call a function while passing it some variables. No problem so far for me. Then the function needs to call another function (it's calling this function multiple times) . When I call the other function within the original function, the original function needs to pass a new variable (already created and made Public) to the other function. However this new variable's name has to be directly influenced by the original variable that I passed to the original function from the Sub. Now I doubt that anyone could follow that because I barely do when reading it so here's an example of what I would like to be able to do.

```
Public Claire As Integer, Stacy As Integer
Public ClaireNotForMe As Integer, StacyNotForMe As Integer
Public Bertha As Integer, Gandalf As Integer
Public BerthaNotForMe As Integer, GandalfNotForMe As Int 
Sub FirstGirls ()
Claire = 1
Stacy = 2
Date_Tonight(Claire, Stacy)
End Sub

Sub QuestionableGirls ()
Bertha = 3
Gandalf = 1000
Date_Tonight(Bertha, Gandalf)
End Sub

Function Date_Tonight (Girl1, Girl2)
Girl1 = Girl1 + 5
TooMuchTalking (Girl1NotForMe)

 ' I want this to pass         ------------------------------------------ClairNotForMe or -------------------------------------------------BerthaNotForMe,On and -----------------------------------------On etc.
Girl2 = 500
End Function

Function TooMuchTalking (Girl)
Girl = 10000
End Function
```

Any advice is appreciated! Can't post exact example because it contains sensitive information. Thanks for even reading.

Comment: I suggest yo start explaining what each function si supposed to do, what the numbers represent.

Comment: I was hoping that, since I'm still very new to programming, that someone would have an easy solution. It doesn't seem like doing something like this should be hard. That's why I just posted a bs code as an example.

Comment: "this new variable's name has to be directly influenced by the original variable that I passed to the original function from the Sub" - by the original variable *name*, or by its *value*?  The name is not accessible, so that would indicate you might need to rethink your approach.  BTW the crux of your example is in that continuous line off to the right, which I didn't even initially see...

Comment: Try creating two arrays - one for {"Claire, "Stacey", etc} and the other for {"ClaireNotForMe, "StaceyNotForMe", etc} then just pass the indices around: from an index your methods can access either one of the arrays.

Comment: Yes influenced by the original passed variable's name, not value. So I guess I do need to consider other options. Thank you for taking a look Tim Williams

Comment: you are using functions, but the functions do  not return any values

Comment: A more conventional approach to programming would be to design a worksheet in which to display certain information, like Row 1 = "Berta" with columns for "Date", "Result", "Evaluation". Next row, next girl's name. "Result" = like "Great, So-so, Forgettable". Evaluation = like "DreamGirl, NotForMe". The you write code which helps you manage what the worksheet displays. You arrive at programming needs which are completely different from those in your question.